# Passing path param is returning object%20Object in URL call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a general axios call varying on my **{accountId}** value in my axios call in ReactJs as below:

**ServiceFactory.js**

```
const devURl = 'https://localhost:3000/service/';
const authToken = '<some_string>';
const accounts = (event) => (
    (accountId) => (
    axios.get(devURl + `accounts/${accountId}/health`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: authToken,
        },
    }).then(response => ({ data: response.data })).catch(error => ({ error }))
    )
);
```

But when I call this in my componentDidMount() as below:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.executeService = this.executeService.bind(this)
        this.state = {
             id : 707
        };
    }
componentDidMount() {
        this.Service = ServiceFactory.accounts();
        this.executeService();
    }

executeService() {
        console.log("in execute")
        this.Service({accountId: this.state.id}).then((response) => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.serviceSuccess(response.data);
            } else {
                this.serviceFailure(response.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

It returns me this URL in my browser:
`https://localhost:3000/service/accounts/[object%20Object]/health`

Can anyone help me how can i pass a path param properly to my axios GET() call.

Comment: You’re passing the method an object and you use it like a value. Pass it just the value, or take the value from the object

Comment: You are calling the this.cachedService but you assigned the account service to the this.Service!!! maybe you should change the calling service to the thisi.Service not this.cachedService

Comment: @AliTorki Sorry My bad i'm calling correct only it just I edited something for posting the question

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can you elaborate a l'il more I am new to this

Comment: What is your babel-preset that you have used?

Comment: @AliTorki I have no idea

Comment: Maybe your transpiler can't transpile this line to a pure string code(devURl + `accounts/${accountId}/health`), so change it to: `${devURl}accounts/${accountId}/health` or devURl + "accounts/" + accountId + "/health"

Comment: Call the service like this: `this.Service(this.state.id)`  instead of  `this.Service({accountId: this.state.id})`

Comment: I think you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your transpiler can't transpile this line to a pure string code:

```js
axios.get(devURl + `accounts/${accountId}/health`, {
```

So change it to:

```js
axios.get(`${devURl}accounts/${accountId}/health`, {
```

or

```js
axios.get(devURl + "accounts/" + accountId + "/health", {
```